# Bounties for first, second and third place

Tags: support, bounty, etiquette

I'd like to start a tiered bounty on an unanswered question I have open.

As I understand the bounty assignments, I would first have to assign a bounty with the third place 'prize'. Once that has been resolved in some manner, I can add a second place 'prize' of no less than double the original. Once the second bounty has been awarded, I can add a third bounty that is at least double the awarded points of the second bounty.

If I've read and interpreted the rules correctly, I should be able to assign bounties of 100 then 250 and finally 500 magical unicorn points to the responses to my question.

Am I on the right track here? I tried this once before on a different StackExchange site a few years ago and was stymied by the algorithms locking up the process. I'd rather not have the same situation reassert itself.

Comment: Just give them all 500 points. Simple

Comment: @Valorum - From my prior experience, I honestly do not know how to do that nor if it can even be accomplished without mod intervention.

Comment: You can award successive bounties

Comment: @Valorum - Yes that's true but only if each new bounty is at least twice what the previous one was. This is one of the logistics that stymied me the last time I tried to do this. TBH, I don't know if you awarded 500 (the maximum of any bounty) the first time then award 500 a second time. I do know you cannot award 1000 not even 501.

Comment: You can keep awarding 500s

Comment: @Valorum - OK. If I can keep awarding the maximum thus bypassing the 'double every new bounty' rule then I'm satisfied with this as an answer. Could you move it from the comment section to somewhere below?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/338462/revisions - see my successive bounties here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this Stack Exchange Meta topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> #### Can I offer a second bounty after the first one has expired? / Can I raise my bounty?
>
> You can offer as many bounties on a question as you want. However, only one bounty can be active on a question at a time. Moreover, any user may have [at most 3 concurrent bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more/104813#104813).
>
> Note that if you offer several bounties on the same question, [you will have to double the amount each time (or more)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639). That is, if your first bounty was worth 50 reputation, your second bounty on the same question will have to be for at least 100, your third for at least 200 and so on. If you've already offered a bounty for more than 250, you can still offer more bounties for 500 (the maximum amount) as long as you like (or as long as you have the rep). This doubling applies only to bounties by the same user on the same question.